# BytesToRead is greater than ReadBufferSize

Tags: c#, serial-port

I'm debugging some serial stuff, the significant part being the SerialDataReceivedEventHandler.

I am observing (via breakpoint and hover-over) that there are almost twice as many bytes to read as the buffer size itself. Like huh ?

This is the code

```
aUartSemaphoreThatTells.WhatTheUartBackgroundRxIsDoing = (int)aValueWhichIndicatesThat.theUARTisReceivingData;

SerialPort CurrentPort = (SerialPort)sender; //// Int routine gave is this in the arguments

int LastByteInUartBuffer = CurrentPort.ReadBufferSize;
int TheNumberOfBytes = CurrentPort.BytesToRead;
byte[] inputData = new byte[TheNumberOfBytes];
int RenameThisInt = CurrentPort.Read(inputData, 0, TheNumberOfBytes);                 //// This is a C# property method of ports

int Dest;
Dest = UartPlaceHolders.RxBufferLeader; //// Will index into buffer for Chief dispatch
```

Doing a little Mouse-Hover-Over tells me that..

- `LastByteInUartBuffer` has 4096
- `TheNumberOfBytes`     has 8092
- `RenameThisInt`        has 8092
- `inputData`            has the right stuff

(I know what the data look like from the other side of the serial port because I generate them myself)

I read over these two pages on the MSDN site,  [ReadBufferSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.io.ports.serialport.readbuffersize%28v=VS.80%29.aspx), and [BytesToRead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.bytestoread%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Anybody, please correct me. How can I get almost 8K of bytes out of a 4K buffer ?

Answer (score 1):

Notice this note on [SerialPort.ReadBufferSize Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.readbuffersize.aspx):

> Because the ReadBufferSize property represents only the
>   Windows-created buffer, it can return a smaller value than the
>   BytesToRead property, which represents both the SerialPort buffer and
>   the Windows-created buffer.

Comment: Details, oh boy. So then, what are those two buffers ?  Are they contiguous ? Just how large can they grow ?  I've already had one problem with too much data too fast; this could elucidate previously mysterious behavior even more.  I don't suppose Microsoft has a page that explains where those buffers come into being, or how they grow. By the way, thanks for showing the whole world how smart I am by pointing out that I missed the second sentence on the page which (I thought) I read. I can't believe I missed that. Thanks anyway. Humility is a desirable character trait.

Comment: Don't worry about misreading the documentation - it happens all the time. But why do you need to know the size of Windows internal buffer? Can't you just read what is available - or what you have room for in your intermediate buffer - which ever is smaller - and just iterate until there is no more?

Comment: @Internal Server Error, I'm sending out packs of 64 bytes, 256 times in a row, in one second. I have to deconstruct them, chop out the protocol overhead, change 24 bit signed ints into 32 bit signed ints, then pass them off to a class which will graph them onto a bunch of lines.  In that context, the 4096 byte buffer was really doing me a favor; i.e., I could 0.25 seconds of data at a time; and it was almost going to solve my night mare for me. Now with the missing hundred bytes, well; so much for sensible code.

Comment: You need a data collection queue or something where you can assemble whole packets (whatever that means in your context) and pass them on to your other logic whenever you have a complete packet ready.

Comment: That's the current scheme in progress. Ugly, but I don't have a better idea. Oh well, we defined the protocol to include a length byte; and then of course it's 16 bits and backwards. I wish I could get paid by the hour for this; be better than practicing law. /Thanks a ton

Answer (score 1):

The answer is actually in the documentation for [`ReadBufferSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.io.ports.serialport.readbuffersize%28v=VS.80%29.aspx):

> The BytesToRead property can return a value larger than the ReadBufferSize property because the ReadBufferSize property represents only the Windows-created buffer while the BytesToRead property represents the SerialPort buffer in addition to the Windows-created buffer.

In this case, the "Windows created buffer" is the underlying driver memory, as opposed to memory allocated by the C# SerialPort object.

Comment: Thanks, now I know another secret.  I couldn't help but notice that the other number was exactly one hundred bytes less than twice the size of the buffer.  Since I just so happen to be sending out multiples of 64 bytes in each little packet, Grrr, that is really irksome.